# Can't get a basic C program to run

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a simple code, that gets two numbers from the user and prints their sum
there it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, sum = 0;
    printf("Insert two numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", n1, n2);
    sum = n1 + n2;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is - %d\n", n1, n2, sum);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, sum);
    getch();
}
```

I'm trying to run it, when i do the first print command gets executed and when i press enter for it to scan it crashes, I'm using code::blocks 13.12 to compile and run
thank you! :)

Comment: Turn on and read your compiler's warnings. Check the docs, especially the _types_ of function parameters and return values.

Answer (score 4):

Your program crashes because you are scanning numbers to wrong memory addresses. Change

```
scanf("%d %d", n1, n2);
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't work because `scanf` takes a pointer to `int`, for each `"%d"` specifier, so pass the address of `n1` and `n2` instead of `n1` and `n2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, sum = 0;
    printf("Insert two numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    /*             ^    ^ address of operater, take the addreess of n2 and pass it */
    /*             | address of operater, take the addreess of n1 and pass it */
    sum = n1 + n2;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is - %d\n", n1, n2, sum);
    printf("%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, sum);
    getch();
}
```

but not just that, you should check that in fact the to numbers where read, otherwise your program will invoke undefined behavior, to make sure you read the integers successfuly you should check the return value of `scanf` it returns the number of arguments matched, so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, sum = 0;
    printf("Insert two numbers:\n");

    /* if it equals two it succeeded, since we requested two integers */
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2) == 2)
    {
        sum = n1 + n2;
        printf("The sum of %d and %d is - %d\n", n1, n2, sum);
        printf("%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, sum);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error reading 2 integers\n");
        return 1; /* non zero means error */
    }
    getch();
    /* return success from main() */
    return 0;
}
```